# Apps and adapters from MobileFirst 8.0 Liberty App on Bluemix disappears

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-server

I have an MFP8 Bluemix service (which is now a Liberty app instead of container). Deployed one hybrid mobile app and 6 adapters.  While things are working fine all of a sudden everything gets wiped off and the server is empty. I have to re-register the app and deploy all the adapters and configure push notification again. This has happened twice and it is very embarrassing when we are in front of customers doing a demo.  Unable to figure out the pattern as to when this happens.  Never had this issue when the MFP8 server was a container. [MFP8 Console that is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuSLA.png)

Answer (score 2):

Anamica,
If you are using the Developer plan, there is no persistent database to store your configuration (including apps and adapters). Everything is on the storage space of your running instance. If there is a restart of the server (because you asked for it or because the server crashed and auto-restarted), you need to redeploy your apps/adapters again. With the Professional plan, you can configure a dashDB database to keep your data in a safe and persistent space.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Jerome.

You can take a backup and restore in case its lost:

(a) Every time you make any changes to admin service, such as deploying an adapter, register an app, etc. run this CLI/command to download all your config into zip file.

```
$curl -X GET -u admin:admin -o export.zip http://<App Name>.mybluemix.net/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/export/all
```

(b) In case you recreate your server and loose your config, run this CLI to import the above config to BMX app.

```
$curl -X POST -u admin:admin -F file=@./export.zip http://<App Name>.mybluemix.net/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/deploy/multi
```

Reference: [Different ways of exporting and importing MobileFirst Foundation server artifacts](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/25/how-to-replicate-mobilefirst-environment/)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The problem is not redeploying.  I have scripts that can be run and deploy the app and adapters from my development environment. The issue is the contents being wiped out and we have no clue when this happens.  5 minutes before client demo everything was working and right in front of the customer I see everything was wiped and definitely I know we never restarted the server or requested for restart.
Also in professional plan do I have to redeploy or will it be stored in dashDB and when the server restarts everything will be deployed and configured again!!